My discord bot does not register the commands
I have created a Discord bot on a server and it has registered all the commands (/) perfectly with this code that reads a folder named “comandos” and gets all the JS extension files:
//Load commands
Client.commands = new Discord.Collection();

fs.readdirSync("./comandos").forEach((commandfile) => {
    const command = require('./comandos/' + commandfile);
    Client.commands.set(command.data.name, command);
});

//Register commands
const REST = new Discord.REST().setToken(config.CLIENT_TOKEN);

(async () => {
    try{
        await REST.put(
            Discord.Routes.applicationGuildCommands(config.clientId, config.guildId),
            {
                body: Client.commands.map((cmd) => cmd.data.toJSON()),
            }
        )
    } catch (e){
      console.log(e);
    }
})();

This is the structure that the JS files usually have where the command is located:
const Discord = require("discord.js");

module.exports = {
    // datos
    data: new Discord.SlashCommandBuilder()
    .setName("test")
    .setDescription("Comando de prueba."),
    //ejecucion
    execute: async (interaction) => {
        //mensaje
        interaction
        .reply("Has ejecutado el comando de prueba.")
        .catch(console.error);
    }
}

When I go to put it on another server they do not appear and I get the following error:

DiscordAPIError[50001]: Missing Access at handleErrors (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:727:13) at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5) at async SequentialHandler.runRequest (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1128:23) at async SequentialHandler.queueRequest (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:959:14) at async _REST.request (C:\Users...@discordjs\rest\dist\index.js:1272:22)
at async C:\Users...\bot.js:36:9 { requestBody: { files: undefined, json: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ] }, rawError: { message: 'Missing Access', code: 50001 }, code: 50001, status: 403, method: 'PUT', url: 'https://discord.com/api/v10/applications/1271441796953800794/guilds/1271149134589595683/commands' }

Note: I know that the error clarifies that it is a lack of permissions but this is rare because it has all (applications.command, bot, Administrator).
The server where I have the problem with the bot is not mine but I have administrator permissions and I checked from top to bottom all the settings of this and there is nothing that should prevent the commands of my bot not to appear. I have rebooted and it is expelled and introduced to the bot but the same issue persists on that server while on the other one nothing happens.

I solved my problem looking in the config.json file, it turns out that I forgot to change the value of guildId which is where the id of the server where I did the tests with the bot was and I just had to change it to the server where it is now.
